# Move EditText (or a layout) above the keyboard when you click a fab

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, keyboard

So, I saw that thing in the Todoist app. When you click the add fab, the keyboard pops up with some layout above it where you can enter text and set some things. How can I do it?

This is how the thing actually looks:

[image]

Is there some example on how this is done?

(please don't mind that this is the iOS version of the app, I don't own a android device)

Comment: post layout code

Comment: This is not a problem with a layout, I want an example or some explanation on how this can be done. It doesn't matter if it is code or just a simple explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make bottom sheet with fragment and edit text in fragment,and set button fab to show bottom sheet when clicked,,you can set the bottomsheet visibility GONE if you want

Comment: I'll try it and let you know how it works, this seems like a good solution.

Comment: The keyboard goes above the bottomsheet.

Comment: Ok, I have something to say about this solution. You need to make just the bottom sheet appear with an edit text. I was forcing a keyboard to show up with the bottom sheet, and this caused some bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Add this `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"`
 line in your Activity block in manifist.xml file like this

```
<activity
            android:name=".Activities.DashboardActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_dashboard"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
```